# Category URL number need removing

Tags: category, url, index

My URLs for categories keep adding numbers at the end of the URL in this format:

/solid-oak-beds-13.html

It is getting increasingly hard to keep track of links, since the urls are not getting created with the URL key I provide.

Is there a simple solution to this? I have tried to reindex, but this simple increases the number.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you have duplicated "URL" of categories. It should be "Unique" for all the categories.

**Solution:**

- Open "core_url_rewrite" table and search for URL in which you are getting numbers. for example, "solid-oak-beds%". Remove all the search result with numbers in URL.

  - Re-Index catalog URL & Clear Cache
  - Add Unique URL in Category and save it.

P.S it will give you 404 error if you had put static category link anywhere in code or in static blocks.

Hope it work and resolved your problem.